# SharePoint 2010 Mysite : How to remove keyword suggestions at Ask Me about and Interests

Tags: my-site

I am using SharePoint 2010 and Outlook 2010.
My Mysite edit profile page  shows some keyword suggestion below About me and Interest field.

**looks like this:**
*Suggestions: (Learn more)
Please click on the appropriate suggestions to add them to your Ask Me About.*

I would like to remove these keywords which might be come from Outlook.

Anybody knows from where these keyword suggestions are stored? and how can I remove these keywords?

Thank you in advance.
-Dany

Answer (score 1):

Click on Edit Profile - In your Ask Me About section you can remove the keywords

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Or at least I can't with my version of SharePoint (2010). The suggestions are not editable in my profile, nor can they be disabled.